# Static Methods and Angular 2 Services in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

While coding an app with Angular 2 and multiple calculation services I faced the following questions:

1. When do I use static in a Angular service provided on application level? Is that nonsense?
2. How does a static method reflect on performance? Lets say a couple hundret objects call at the same time the same static method. Is this method instantiated more than once?

This is a snap of the class, that provides me multiple calculation methods and is instantiated on application level:

```
@Injectable()
export class FairnessService {
  constructor(){}
  private static calculateProcentValue(value: number, from: number): number {
    return (Math.abs(value) / Math.abs(from)) * 100;
  }
  public static calculateAllocationWorth(allocation: Allocation): number {
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: private static? :o

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. *Static* methods of a class, unlike *instance* methods, belong to (are visible on) the class itself (**not an instance of it**). They do not depend on the instance members of a class and will usually take input from the parameters, perform actions on it, and return some result. They act independently.

They do make sense in Angular services. There are situations where we can't / don't actually need to use an instance of the service, and we can't / don't want to make a new dependency on it, we only need access to the methods our service carries. Here *static* members come in.

The example of using the static method defined in the service:

```
import { FairnessService } from './fairness.service';

export class MyComponent {

    constructor() {
        // This is just an example of accessing the static members of a class.
        // Note we didn't inject the service, nor manually instantiate it like: let a = new A();
        let value = FairnessService.calculatePercentValue(5, 50);
        let value2 = FairnessService.calculatePercentValue(2, 80);

        console.log(value); // => 10
        console.log(value2); // => 2.5
    }
}
```

2. *Static* methods have no impact on the performance. As we've ascertained above, they do not depend on any instance of the class, and invoking those methods will in no way instantiate the class.

For more information, it's explained well on: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: As I understand it, at least 1 instance of every instance is created in Angular when either added to the providers list of a module or added to the 'providedIn': root. I still struggle to understand what is the difference between static or instance methods in a singleton service. I actually don't see any use-case for non-singleton services either but that is another matter I guess...could you provide any additional info if you have it?

Comment: This does kinda defeat the theoretical purpose of having a dependency injection container, which would allow you to swap out `FairnessService` for some other `NotSoFairService` at runtime without having to change the `FairnessService` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

My answer before was based on a limited understanding.  The static methods are available on a class itself, not on one of it's instantiations.

Here's an article that can explain this concept:
https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods

seidme's answer is also solid.

**Original**

Static methods are represented as global variables (I think?) in the Angular application, so I think they would only be instantiated once each.  Therefore I think it would not have a large impact on performance (relative to an instantiation of the class for each component that needs it.)

I use static when I don't want to inject the service and get an instance just to leverage context-agnostic formatting/utility methods.  Application-wide versions of these don't seem unreasonable to me.

Comment: If that's the case it's amazing, I always thought you had to inject services in order to use them :o

Comment: The "Inject" is for the DI process I believe, so if you need an instance of a service, then it must be injected.  However, if it's a static class (i.e. no instance!), then no need for an instance, so no need for DI, and therefore no need for @Injectable :)

Comment: But how do you create a static class? His example isn't a static class right?

Comment: you can't use the `static` keyword on the class definition -- I just declare only static members.  You are right that the exported class itself is not inherently static.

Comment: static methods are not global variables. If you check how Typescript is transpiled to Javascript then you can see they assigned to the Function object of a class instead of its Object object so yes they are created only once for the typescript class itself rather than for each instance of it. But they are not global variables :)

Comment: I wonder if there is any advantage to static services over using the `import * as StaticService from 'static.service.ts' where the methods in that file are simply constants that reference exported pure functions?

Comment: @user2528534 There isn't any benefit one way or the other. What is beneficial is using static/plain functions when appropriate and not trying to force everything into class instances--the Angular folks are just a little bit special..

Comment: Great answer @chrispy! Thank you. Could you explain how to use a static method from a service within a component's view?

Comment: @BenRacicot Angular views only have access to instance methods and properties, so you need to have a local variable assigned to the static method to get access to it.

Comment: class YourComponent {  const localVar = StaticService.property } // localVar accessable in view