# Angular 2 inject service to Utilities class

Tags: angular

I have a Utilities class with some static methods on it.

In one method I want to get an object and return a safe style of its image.

The issue is I need to use the DomSanitizer service, and I am unable to use it in static method.
Here is the code:

```
export class Utilities{

   constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
   }


   static getImageStyle(obj){
          return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(data:image/jpg;base64,${obj.image})`);

   }

}
```

Does this need to be done in a non-static method and I should create instance of the class every time I use this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861092/static-methods-and-angular-2-services-in-javascript-es6) static functions do not use the instance of the class. there for if you declare a service in the constructor it wont be available in static methods.

why not just make `Utilities` also a service and add `sanitizer:DomSanitizer` to the utilies service constructor like you did?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess I will need to do it as a service. I wanted to avoid it as I already used this Utilities in many places...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass Injector to the static function as a parameter and then use injector.get() to get instance of DomSanitizer.

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#appendix-working-with-injectors-directly