# Angular Custom validator: why export function?

Tags: angular, angular7, customvalidator

I'm doing my first steps in Angular and had to make a custom maximum validator for a number field in a template form. This is it:

```js
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaximumValue]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MaximumValueDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class MaximumValueDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appMaximumValue') maximumValue: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.maximumValue ? maximumValueValidator(this.maximumValue)(control) : null;
  }
}

export function maximumValueValidator(minimum: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    return control.value > minimum ? {'maximumValue': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

After thinking about it I discovered that it also works without the export function:

```js
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaximumValue]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MaximumValueDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class MaximumValueDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appMaximumValue') maximumValue: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return Number(control.value) > this.maximumValue ? {'maximumValue': {value: control.value}} : null;
  }
}
```

So my question is, what is the reason for this export function?

Comment: When injecting the class in a different component/service, you can use it's methods. This is the reason you don't need to export the validate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you export the maximumValueValidator, you can also use the validator logic directly inside TS files by importing the function.

The directive can only be used in HTML files, so for the use of your form it will do without the export.

If you want to use the validation inside your TS files for some reason, you can if you export the maximumValueValidator function since this is the real logic of your validator.

If you are not planning to do this validation in your TS files as well, you can remove the export for maximumValueValidator.

Comment: Well the obvious reason to use it in the .ts file would be a reactive form... that explains it quite well thank you

Answer (score 0):

"export" key word is a necessary when you want to use the specific class or specific function in other classes or functions. Without exporting we can't import those classes or functions.

e.g.,

`export class HomeComponent {}`

```
export function ValidatorFunction {}
```

in the other class, you can use

`import { HomeComponent } from '/somelocation';`

`import { ValidatorFunction } from '/somelocation';`

However, when it comes to this specific scenario, you need not import this because it is a **static** method.Please refer below link.
[Static Methods and Angular 2 Services in JavaScript ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861092/static-methods-and-angular-2-services-in-javascript-es6)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to export the function if the validator's logic is going to be used in multiple places.

Also, in your case, you could use the **built-in** [`max` validator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L159-L169), available under `Validators.max`

```js
@Directive({})
export class YourDirective implements Validator {
 @Input() maxValue: number

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('maxValue' in changes) {
      this.createValidator();
    }
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.validator ? this.validator(control) : null;
  }

  private createValidator(): void {
    this.validator = this.maxValue ? Validators.max(this.maxValue) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you listed above basically implements a Validator for two different kinds of forms.

The approach with a directive is useful if you are going for [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms), while the function below that would be needed is you want to control your form with your .ts-files, meaning you are going for [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

These work differently and are used quite differently as well.
While for one case you would have something like

```
HTML:
<input type="number" appMaximumValue="5" />
```

You would go for

```
HTML:
<input type="number" formControlName="myControl" />

ts:
form = new FormGroup({
  'myControl': new FormControl(0, maximumValueValidator(5));
});
```

in the case of reactive forms.

You can read more about that in the official docu [form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)